# AX2012: Capture SysInfoAction on form initialization

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

**Situation:**
I am opening a form via a *SysInfoAction* (*SysInfoAction_FormrunQuery* to be exact) from an error message (info log) as follow (Compressed a bit):

```
query.addDataSource(tableNum(WDPErrorLogView)).addRange(fieldNum(WDPErrorLogView, ErrorOutboundMessage)).value(SysQuery::value(resultRecId));
error("@WDP1299", '', SysInfoAction_FormrunQuery::newFormnameQuery(formStr(WDPErrorLog), query));
```

**Problem:**
The form I am calling here, has multiple tabs, since it can be opened with queries from various tables. I would like to capture this calling record to not only filter on the record passed (This already happens thanks to the *SysInfoAction*), but also make the appropriate tab page active.

I thought that *element.args().record()* would contain this calling record, but to my surprise it does not. Any ideas how to could get hold of this record... or, at least its table id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy.  Just add a parmMethod for an object/caller to `\Classes\SysInfoAction_FormrunQuery`.  Copy the static method `newFormnameQuery` and call it `newFormnameQueryWithCaller` for example and then add an extra argument, then set that argument in your parm method with the same style as `newFormnameQuery`.

Then in your `\Classes\SysInfoAction_FormrunQuery\run`, where it sets up the `args` record, just add `args.caller(...)` and set your caller object if it exists.

Comment: I will use this solution, if there is no way to do this using existing architecture. Did not want to duplicate code, so thought I would ask here :) - Thanks Alex.